# iOS 8 Bluetooth LE Central can't write value for characteristic 2A06

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am working on an iPhone app and need to write value on the bluetooth low energy device that support  [Immediate Alert service](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServiceViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.service.immediate_alert.xml) using CoreBluetooth framework on iOS 7.0 and 8.0. Connection with the device working perfectly but whenever i try to write a value on the device nothing is happening (the value is not saved on device. So, device is not ringing). 
Below is the code used for writing value:

```
+ (void)writeValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral alarm:(BOOL)alarm
{    
    NSData  * data = nil;
    if (alarm) {
        uint8_t value = 2;
        data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&value length:sizeof(value)];
    } else {
        uint8_t value = 0;
        data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&value length:sizeof(value)];
    }
    [peripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse];
}
```

Logs and status of device before the execution above code:

```
- (void)beginAlarm
{
    NSLog(@"characteristic : %@",discAlertCharacteristic);
    NSLog(@"peripheral : %@",discPeripheral);
    NSLog(@"service : %@",service);

    [BluetoothUtility writeValueForCharacteristic:discAlertCharacteristic peripheral:discPeripheral alarm:YES];
}
```

```
characteristic : CBCharacteristic: 0x146ea8d0, UUID = 2A06, properties = 0x14, value = (null), notifying = NO
service : CBService: 0x146ecc90, isPrimary = YES, UUID = 1802
peripheral : CBPeripheral: 0x146dd110, identifier = B0A195DC-7273-B3F5-BA70-0219A61F8904, name = LA-TAG a87, state = connected
```

I have tested my Bluetooth device using [BLE Utility app](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/ble-utility/id606210918?mt=8) and its working properly.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing is happening"? The value is not saved to the peripheral?

Comment: Also please show the code which prints the logs you posted (in which methods are the logs printed?).

Comment: Your code looks fine. Do you call `discoverCharacteristics:forService:` on `peripheral` before `beginAlarm` is called?

Comment: Yes, I've called discoverCharacteristics:forService method before beginAlarm

Comment: Are your peripheral, service and characteristic variables all retained/strong properties?

Comment: Set the delegate and implement peripheral:didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error: . Did you received positive result?

Comment: i am also working with the same scenario that i can send immediate alert sound to BLE device and receive from it as well . so how did you solve that issue ? can you or anyone guide me through its methods and working  ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (getCharacteristic.properties.rawValue == 0xE){

              let sentValue:[UInt8] = [0x38, 0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD, 0xEE, 0xFF, 0x02]

              let sentData = Data(bytes: sentValue)

              self.peripheralDevice.writeValue(sentData, for: getCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)

 }
```